How do phosphorescent panels compare to LEDs for whole of night low level lightinhg
Modern phosphorescent materials are used for applications like emergency exit signs and evacuation markers.
I'm wondering if the best of these may be acceptable for low level all night low level lighting? (Say 10 hours operation).
What sort of light levels could I expect and what is the equivalent LED power needed to match or exceed this?

Brightness of Phosphorescent lighting compared to low energy LED lighting
Summary:
A top performance modern LED will deliver in excess of 200 lumen per watt. At currents below 10 mA forward voltage drop is typically about 2.7 - 2.8 volts.
At 0.1 mA LED power = 0.28 mW and at 200 l/W
light output is about 56 milli-lumen (0.056 lumen).
A top of class phosphorescent material will deliver the following lumens from 1 square metre of material after the stated times post excitation.
10 min - 1.268l
30 min - 0.390l
60 min - 0.166l
120min - 0.073l
600min - 0.011l
So, for a 1 square metre sheet the PP output drops below LED output after about 2 hours.
BUT PP material costs in the order of $40 or more per square metre in volume.
An A4 sheet of PP outputs 1/16th of the above light levels.
3 x good quality AA Alkaline cells will provide the above calculated 55 milli-lumen at 10 hours per night for in excess of 5 years.
Adding a PIR person sensor (50 uA current) and a daylight sensor (~- an LDR a FET and a resistor) will allow somewhat higher light levels when needed.
(PIR about 50% of LED current. LED and PIR off in daylight)
Good quality PP material in finished sheet form typically has claimed lifetimes of maybe 6-8 years indoors and 4-6 years outdoors.

Conclusion
Unless there was an exceptionally compelling reason to not use a LED and battery system then the PP system is a very poor choice.
Light levels for say an A4 panel is below to far below a 3 AA battery,  5 year life LED system. A one square metre PP is brighter than a 3AA,  5 year LED solution for about two hours if full excitation is available. If daylight is used for excitation an overcast or rainy day will probably produce lower or much lower light levels.
An LED can be easily and cheaply focused onto a desired smaller and/or custom area. A PP's light is very much harder and costlier to focus and shape.
If battery recharging is permissible (solar or other) then an LED solution will always be vastly superior.
_____________________________________________________________
PPs (phosphorescent panels) have the obvious advantage of potentially non-electronic recharging. This could be from daylight, but is often from usually-on artificial lighting, with the PP being used when primary power fails.
PPs and related phosphorescent materials have a brightness specification based on international standards. This is largely because they are used in emergency exit and guidance systems and a formal way of comparing and certifying them is required. Light output per square metre is usually specified in time after initial excitation by whatever means. Light output units are mcd/m^2 (millicandella per square metre) Standard times after excitation are 10 minutes, one hour and the time to fall to less than about 0.3 mcd/m^2.
Manufacturers may supply additional brightness/time data. 
mcd (millicandella) are a measure of brightness.
Light output of a PP is specified in millicandella per square metre.(mcd/m^2)
lumen are also a measure of light output.
LED light output is usually specified in lumen.
A convenient & fortunate fact is that for one square metre of material 
mcd/m^2 = lumens.
The best phosphorescent material that I have found has ratings of
.......... mcd/m^2 ........... lumen per square metre 
10 min - 1268 mcd/m^2    1.268 
30 min -  390 mcd/m^2     0.390 
60 min -  166 mcd/m^2     0.166
.120min -   73 mcd/m^2     0.073
.600min -   11 mcd/m^2     0.011
(This is for a powder. A panel made with this will not be 100% phosphorescent material and will probably be less bright).
SO 1 square metre of PP outputs the same number of lumen as its mcd/m^2 figure. Note these are milli-candella so you get the matching milli-lumen.
3 x AA good quality cells will drive a top class LED for 3000 hours at an output of 0.5 lumen (500 milli-lumen)
ie lower than the PP's 10 minute figure
   About the same as the 30 and 60 minute figures (500 versus 390 and 166)      About 3 times as much light as the PP at 1 hour      
About 7 times as much light as the PP at 2 hours
 About 50 times as much light as the PP at 10 hours
BUT that is for a 1 square metre PP - probably about $US40-$50 of material wholesale in volume.
An A4 panel costs 1/16th the price of a square metre but outputs 1/16th the light.
A PP radiates light over a very wide area.
An LED can be focused as desired. 
So eg an A4 PP using the above material would give ABOUT 0.020 lumen at 1 hour (LED = 0.500) and under .001 lumen at 10 hours (LED still equals 0.500).
OR: 3 x AA good quality cells operating at 0.1 mA will give about 0.050 lumen for 30,000 hours = about 8 years, notionally.
Better than a square metre PP after 2 hours.
Better than A4 PP after about 20 minutes. 
Cells have both load based lifetime and age based decay so 5 years is probably a reasonable target.  The best AA Alkaline cells are rated at 3000 mAh at 10 mA continuous and tests demonstrate they are typically 20%+ better at 1 mA.
On an eg A5 sheet the 0.050 lumen provide about 1.6 lumen per square metre.
A "pathetic" amount of light, but enough to read 12 point type on an A5 sheet. 


Added 240604:
Q: Andy asked " ... I came away thinking that LED solutions will win every time over phosphorescent panels but, maybe that's not true so, for me, it would help if you could explain where phosphorescent panels win-out.
A: Note that for reasons outside the scope of this post, the LED solution must be a non-rechargeable one. This has the advantage of no wiring, easy install, no separately stealable panel and more.
IF solar PV charging is allowed the LED solution is vastly superior.
As noted above "Unless there was an exceptionally compelling reason to not use a LED and battery system then the PP system is a very poor choice." There may be situations where there are compelling reasons. That decision is outside my control.
I'm peripherally involved with an organisation who are looking at using PPs for low level lighting in extreme developing country situations.
I'm developing LED solutions and so am potentially biased. Others are also looking at PP solutions.
Regardless of source, in some cases in situations of absolute darkness, a tiny amount of light can be extremely valuable.
At the light levels concerned, using the phosphorescent material that I have (imported from China at $42/m^2 - the best I could find) I can match an A4 sized panel (1/16 m^2) after less than an hour with a 150 microamp 2.6V white LED. For the rest of the night the LED is vastly brighter than the exponentially dimming panel. [150 uA or about 4 milliwatts (!) is exceptionally dim, but allows eg a sheet of A5 12-point text to be read with relative ease, and provides useful lighting over a significantly greater area.
Using non rechargeable batteries eg 3 x AA quality Alkaline give 5 years x 10hrs/night. BUT - Even sealed batteries are a theft target.
Electronics should be reliable.
A PP panel SHOULD be slightly more so done well.
Panel material costs $42/16 = $US2.68 for an A4 sized sheet before mounting, & solar light for charging is needed.
An LED with 3 x AA batteries and a daylight sensor should be cost competitive.
A PIR (50 uA, $US1) allows brighter light on-demand if occupancy rate isn't too high. Example only:  If occupancy was 10% over a 10 hour night = 1 hour than an always-on 150 uA LED requires 1500 uA-hrs whereas an always active 50 uA PIR requires 500 uA-hour.
So, for equal energy use a 1 hour on-time LED can use 1000 uA (1 mA) and so be about 6 times brighter when operating. If instead occupancy was 2 hours/night then the LED can use 500 uA and be about 3 times as bright.
or
A capacitive switch allows brightup from say 50 uA to a few mA.
Or ... .

It's an interesting subject but, I came away thinking that LED solutions will win every time over phosphorescent panels but, maybe that's not true so, for me, it would help if you could explain where phosphorescent panels win-out. Maybe I missed it somewhere?

@Andyaka In most cases LED solutions will be superior. ie as above  "Unless there was an exceptionally compelling reason to not use a LED and battery system then the PP system is a very poor choice." || I'm peripherally involved with an organisation who are looking at using PPs for low level lighting in extreme developing country situations. At the light levels concerned using the material I have (imported from China at $42/m^2 - the best I could find) I can match an A4 panel after less than an hour with a 150 microamp 2.6V LED. For the rest of the night the LED is vastly brighter. BUT ...

@Andy ... Using non rechargeables eg 3 x AA quality Alkaline give 5 years x 10hrs/night. || Even sealed batteries are a theft target. Electronics should be reliable. A PP panel SHOULD be slightly more so done well. Panel material costs $42/16 = $US2.68 for A4 before mounting, & solar light for charging is needed. An LED with 3 x AA and a daylight sensor should be cost competitive. A PIR (50 uA) allows brighter light in demand if usage isn't too high. Or a capacitive switch allows brightup from say 50 uA to a few mA. Or ... . The decisions are not mine. This is intended to be educational.

@Andyaka  I've added an expansion of the above comments to the end of the answer

In the daylight hours I wonder how much energy can be restored with a small solar panel and an ultracap. Probably not an economical solution. Just saying.

@Andyaka  Very roughly you can hope to deliver about 1 Ws per farad from a 2.x VC supercap. Lifetimes are liable to be less long than I'd hoped when I looked at this approach earlier this year. Many are 1000 hour, 85C. Some are 2000h. || Digikey show a 1.5F 5.5V cap for about $US1 in 10k quantity. (Only 100h at 70C so very marginal). That's about 20 J discharged 5,5V to 3V. About 0.5 mW all night so marginal. Matching very adequate mW PV panel is well under $US1 - so a potential. BUT a separate PV panel is not wanted :-(. || I can do a FAR better rechargeable battery solution if allowed.
